# How to change API address for each Fragment from same DataSource class?

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-paging

I'm using **Paging Library** from **JetPack** for infinite scrolling. Everything is working fine, but I have more **API addresses**(URLs).

And what I want to do is for my fragments to change the **URL** but I don't know what function should I create to fetch each **URL** for the respective fragment.

I've tried a function to fetch each **URL** based on which Fragment is opened with a **SortType class**

**Function to fetch:**

```
     private fun fetchPhotos(page : Int): Call<List<Photo>> {
    if (sortType != null) {
        return dataSource.fetchPhotos(sortType = sortType, page = page)
    } else if (query.isNotEmpty()) {
        return dataSource.fetchPhotos(page = page, query = query)
    }
    throw RuntimeException("Unknown state to fetch movies")
}
```

Here is **PhotoDataSource** where is the Pagination and where pages are fetched and **API URLs:**

```
  override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<Int>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, Photo>) {
    networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING)
    initialLoad.postValue(NetworkState.LOADING)

    fetchPhotos.getPhotos(FIRST_PAGE_NUMBER, params.requestedLoadSize).enqueue(object : Callback<List<Photo>>{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Photo>>, t: Throwable) {
            // keep a Completable for future retry
            setRetry(Action { loadInitial(params, callback) })
            val error = NetworkState.error(t.message)
            // publish the error
            networkState.postValue(error)
            initialLoad.postValue(error)            }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Photo>>, response: Response<List<Photo>>) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                setRetry(null)
                networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED)
                initialLoad.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED)
                callback.onResult(response.body()!!, null, FIRST_PAGE_NUMBER + INCREMENT_PAGE_VALUE)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**API Services:**

```
@GET("photos")
fun getPhotos(@Query("page") page: Int, @Query("per_page") per_page: Int): Call<List<Photo>>

@GET("photos/curated")
fun getCuratedPhotos(@Query("page") page: Int, @Query("per_page") per_page: Int): Call<List<Photo>>

@GET("/collections/featured")
fun getFeaturedCollections(@Query("page") page: Int, @Query("per_page") per_page: Int): Call<List<Photo>>

@GET("search/photos")
fun searchPhotos(@Query("page") page: Int, @Query("query") query: String): Call<List<Photo>>
```

**SortType class:**

```
enum class SortType(val value: Int) {
   MOST_POPULAR(0),
   HIGHEST_RATED(1),
   UPCOMING(2) 
}
```

I get no errors and nothing happens. I just want a way to make this more productive and I want to avoid creating a **DataSource class** for each **API URL**.

Hope you understand, I really need your help I've been struggling with this error for a few months and no idea what should I do. For any better explanations just ask.